# Using the URLconf defined in SchoolnSkill.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django

Ok, this is a very common problem that Django people face, and there are a couple of articles already available on the internet,but none of them helps me. I do understand that I need to create my own URLPatterns in my "apps/url", and which I have created one. Below is the URLPatterns from my project"schoolnskill/url":

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^user_info/', include('user_info.urls', namespace='user_info')),

]
```

Below is the url patterns from my apps user_info/url

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user_info/index/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^user_info/register/$', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='sign_up'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

]
```

I am getting error for "user_info/index" even though I have added it in my URL Patterns.

Below is the whole error stack:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_info/index/
Using the URLconf defined in SchoolnSkill.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^user_info/ ^user_info/index/$ [name='index']
^user_info/ ^user_info/register/$ [name='sign_up']
^user_info/ ^register/$ [name='register']
The current path, user_info/index/, didn't match any of these
```

My Python environment details:

```
Python - 3.6
Django - 1.11.3
IDE - Spyder 3.2.4
```

New error after removing 'user_info'

```
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
IndexView is missing a QuerySet. Define IndexView.model, IndexView.queryset, or override IndexView.get_queryset()
```

Comment: You need to import other urls only in your <projectfolder>/urls.py , you don't need to import in all urls.py.

Comment: @ sandeep, as per my understanding goes,  <projectfolder>/urls.py is only to give the link to the urls available inside my apps, and I needed to create another url.py inside my "apps/" to insert all my urls there. Since "register" is working on me so I must be doing something wrong about just " index" part

Answer (score 0):

You already have `user_info/` when you use `include()` in your root url config.

Therefore you should remove it from `user_info/urls.py`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='sign_up'),
    # this url pattern now clashes with the one above, so you need to change it if you need both
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

Comment: @user3521180 "not working" is not enough information to help.

Comment: I gave the error that I was facing. I removed 'user_info' from 'user_info/index', and now the error is different , and added in my main query

Comment: As the error says, you need to set a model or queryset for your index view, e.g. `views.IndexView.as_view(model=MyModel)`. If you're still stuck, please ask a new question since it's a completely different issue. You'll need to specify what you want the index view to display.

Comment: ok, since I know that my index page is still blank and has nothing in it, so may be I am getting that error, I am done with this query as I got what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are not importing the urlpatterns from you user_info app?

at the top of your schoolnskill urls.py file write

`from project_name.user_info import urlpatterns`

then in your url include statement write:

`url(r'^user_info/', include(urlpatterns))`